# Right way of handling errors and keep going

Tags: c#, optimization, exception

We have a requirement of parsing/validating a large number of rows read from CSV or Excel files. We read the row and apply business rules to check if all the cells/columns contain the valid data.

The application should keep validating records/columns till end even if some error occurs at an error or column. Currently we are going like this:

```
private void ValidateRow(RowObject obj)
{
    try
    {
        foreach(var col in obj.Cells)
        {
            ValidateColumn(col);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //LOG ERROR
    }
}
```

The columns are validates like this:

```
public void ValidateColumn(ColumnObject c)
{
    try
    {
        //validate c
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //LOG Column Error
    }
}
```

We are handling error at two places when validating rows (`ValidateRow`) and then for each column (`ValidateColumn`). My question is whether this is valid or optimal way of handling error or something more optimal be done?

Comment: Validation errors do not seem like *exceptional* conditions. Rather, it seems like you *expect* some of the data to possibly be invalid, that's why you have `Validate` methods. Therefore, it seems like using exceptions in the first place is poor design.

Comment: Do you *really* want to handle all exceptions? What about `OutOfMemoryException`, `TypeLoadException` and `AppDomainUnloadedException` for example?

Comment: @CodyGray The aim is that even if any call to `ValidateColumn` or `ValidateRow` fails the program should continue to next line. Yes I am doubtful about this design that is the main reason I'm putting it out here.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes any of these and many other exceptions occur. what do you suggest? any pattern or best practice?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Well, I think you should only handle exceptions that you "expect" - but ones like `TypeLoadException` indicate very serious problems and you should probably allow them to propagate and bring down the program.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I understand the thing but it is a windows service and I want that if anything bad happens with one file/row/column other things should not get affected.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Well, in the event of such a serious exception, how do you know that other things haven't already been affected? The results could be way off...

Comment: Right, my point is that if you're throwing an exception and immediately handling it just to log it *in the same method*, then there's no reason to throw an exception at all. This is an abuse of exceptions. Just use error codes and `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know your Business logic it's difficult to tell. But I would recommend to evaluate all possible exceptions and handle them in different `catch` blocks. This enables you to handle errors more specific. A good hint is to use Microsofts StyleCop and FxCop. They help you to write good code. In this case they would tell you to not catch general Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is very correct and optimal. If you want to keep going, you should always have a try/catch inside the foreach. But I guess you don't really need the outer try/catch in this case as it will only fail if obj or obj.Cells is null. Unless you have posted only part of your code. Though I agree with comments that validation should not throw exception in the first place but if you are using some 3d party library or any complex code that you are not sure of, it's better to handle it the way you did.